# What is the basic idea of Topology

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I am currently studying mathematics at a master's level, but oddly my first topology course ever will be next term... So I'm wondering some basic things:

$1)$ What role does topology serve in an overall view of mathematics (for example, measure theory can be seen as a certain abstraction of real analysis to measure spaces)

$2)$ What do people mean when they say "The topology on"?  For example "The topology on $\mathbb{R}$", or the topology induced by a certain metric, etc

$3)$ What would be a good source of pre-requisite self study?

Comment: "*Metric spaces* can be thought of as very basic spaces, with only a few axioms, where the ideas of *convergence* and *continuity* exist. The fundamental ingredient that is needed to make these concepts rigorous is that of a distance, also called a metric [...] even more general spaces, called *topological spaces*, in which pure convergence is studied without reference to distances." From Joseph Muscat, *Functional Analysis : An Introduction to Metric Spaces Hilbert Spaces and Banach Algebras*, Springer (2014)

Comment: Here are some good books on topology
by Hatcher: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf
by Munkres: Topology


One can connect topology to group theory by study the fundamental group of a topological space. We can try to deduce from properties of topological spaces the property of its fundamental group. for example, we could ask the question what property does the topological space has to have in order for its fundamental group to be coherent(attempt on Baumslag conjecture).

Comment: What to expect depends on the emphasis of the course. If it heads towards algebraic topology, then you might learn about understanding and distinguishing different sorts of holes in shapes (that may not always be as nice as a manifold). But if it avoids that, then the focus might be more on how far properties of continuous functions can be generalized.

Comment: I like to say: Topology is geometry without actual measuring.

Answer (score 1):

1. I recommend looking into the various implications Tychonoff's theorem has; on the most basic level I'm aware of - this theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice within our working system. This theorem simply states the a product of compact space is compact, equipped with the correct topology.
2. A topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ with the following properties;

a. $\emptyset , X \in \tau$

b. the union of elements in $\tau$ is again an element in $\tau$

c. the finite intersection of elements is again an element.

I recommend thinking about these axioms in context of the familiar open ball toplogy on $\mathbb{R}$.

3. Munkres Topology is extremely accessible and covers a nice chunk of point set topology